# What does ∇∇:Q mean?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm reading a paper from the 1960's on Electromagnetism, and I wanted to know what the symbol ∇∇:Q (where Q is the Electric Quadrupole) means. Is this just the Laplacian? See Below [image].

Comment: Peraphs $\nabla^2$? Do the textbook use CGS unit?

Answer (score 1):

The expression is $\nabla \nabla : Q$. I suspect that $:$ refers to the [dyadic "double dot-product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics), so that
$$
\nabla \nabla = \pmatrix{
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} 
& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y} 
& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial z}
& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}
& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial x}
& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial y}
& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}
},
$$
and $\nabla \nabla : Q = \sum_{i,j = 1}^3 \frac{\partial^2Q_{ij}}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$, where $x_1 = x, x_2 = y, x_3 = z$.